# Malloc, dynamically allocating wrong size memory for a string

Tags: arrays, c, char, malloc, sizeof

```
int main() {
    char A[200], B[200];
    printf("Enter 2 words or sentences.\n");
    gets(A);
    gets(B);
    char* C = (char*)malloc((strlen(A) + strlen(B)) * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(A); i++)
        C[i] = A[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(B); i++)
        C[i + strlen(A)] = B[i];
    printf("%s", C);
}
```

The initial value of `C` is `ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍýýýý`, which is 4 symbols longer than requested and the 4 symbols also show up as output when printing `C`. I have no idea why there are 4 symbols, which is why I'm here seeking an explanation.

Comment: the memory returned by malloc contains junk, you have to set it to something, printf (I assume you are doing that) on unitiialized memory produces undefined behavior

Comment: I give values for the first 10 symbols and print the whole string which I expect to contain just the 10 symbols.

Comment: since you dont show any code for a) loading values or b) printing its hard to work out what your issue is. My guess, you are using %s output and did not 0 terminate. PLease post all your code in the question

Comment: Obligatory: [Why is the `gets` function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2505965)

Answer (score 3):

Problems:

**Not *null character* terminated**

Code attempts `printf("%s", C);` which is *undefined behavior* as `C[]` is not a *string* as needed by `"%s"`.

```
// Append a \0
C[strlen(A) + strlen(B)] = '\0';
```

**Insufficient memory allocated**

Make room for the *null character*.

```
// (strlen(A) + strlen(B)) * sizeof(char)
strlen(A) + strlen(B) + 1
```

**`gets()` is no longer part of the standard C library since C11**

Use `fgets()` and lop off a  potential trailing `'\n'` for similar behavior.

**`int` vs. `size_t`**

`int` is insufficient for very long strings.  `size_t` works for all strings.

**Avoid potentially recalculating the string length**

---

```
int main(void) {
    char A[200], B[200];
    printf("Enter 2 words or sentences.\n");

    // Code should check the return value of fgets()
    // Omitted for brevity.
    fgets(A, sizeof A, stdin);

    A[strcspn(A, "\n")] = '\0'; // Lop off potential \n
    fgets(B, sizeof B, stdin);
    B[strcspn(B, "\n")] = '\0';

    size_t A_len = strlen(A);
    size_t B_len = strlen(B);
    char* C = malloc(A_len + B_len + 1);

    if (C) {
      for (size_t i = 0; A[i]; i++) {
        C[i] = A[i];
      }
      for (size_t i = 0; B[i]; i++) {
        C[A_len + i] = B[i];
      }
      C[A_len + B_len + i] = '\0';

      printf("%s\n", C);
      free(C);  // Good housekeeping to free allocations.
    }
}
```

Comment: Corner cases: if `fgets` fails, there's no telling what's in the buffer.

Comment: @cHao Almost true.  When `fgets(A)` returns `NULL` due to input error, `A[]` is indeterminate. When `fgets(A)` returns `NULL` due to end-of-file, `A[]` is unchanged.  IAC, checking the return value of `fgets()` is more robust.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` just returns a pointer to some memory it allocated for you. It doesn't initialize that memory, zero it out, or anything like that.  So what you're seeing when you print it out, is whatever junk was in there before.

Frankly, you're lucky you didn't open up a wormhole or something. C strings are nul-teminated, so when you pass that pointer around, you're technically not passing a string yet. When you pass it to a function that expects a string, all kinds of wackiness can ensue.

You should initialize the memory when you get it. The simplest initialization would be something like `*C = '\0';` or `C[0] = '\0';`, which turns the memory into a zero-length string. But you probably already have something to put there, or why would you be allocating memory in the first place?  :P

Now that there's code, we can tweak it a bit to fix the issue...

```
int main() {
    char A[200], B[200];
    printf("Enter 2 words or sentences.\n");

    // BTW: you should never, ever be using `gets`.
    // use `fgets` and pass the size of your buffer to avoid overruns.
    // note: it returns a null pointer if it fails...at which point you
    // can't trust that A and B are strings, and should probably bail
    if (!fgets(A, sizeof A, stdin)) return 1;
    if (!fgets(B, sizeof B, stdin)) return 1;

    // you don't want to call `strlen` over and over. save these lengths
    size_t Alen = strlen(A);
    size_t Blen = strlen(B);

    // lop off the newlines
    if (Alen && A[Alen - 1] == '\n') A[--Alen] = '\0';
    if (Blen && B[Blen - 1] == '\n') B[--Blen] = '\0';

    // You need enough space for both strings, plus a nul at the end.
    // side note: you don't need to cast the pointer to a `char *`.
    // also, sizeof(char) is 1 by definition, so no need to multiply by it.
    char* C = malloc(Alen + Blen + 1);
    if (!C) return 1;

    // compare to the length variable instead
    for (int i = 0; i < Alen; i++)
        C[i] = A[i];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Blen; i++)
        C[i + Alen] = B[i];

    // important: nul-terminate the string
    C[Alen + Blen] = '\0';

    printf("%s", C);

    // not strictly necessary at the end of main on a modern OS, but
    // you should free what you malloc
    free(C);
}
```

Comment: @chux : ooo....crafty.  Didn't even consider feeding a nul to stdin.  :P  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

`C[strlen(A) + strlen(B)] = '\0';` after the `malloc` gets rid of the junk, thanks everyone for the ideas.

Comment: No it doesn't because you haven't allocated space for that array position. So you are accessing the array out of bounds, if it works it is by pure (un)luck.